# Not getting all element of a dynamic ListView on Selenium + Appium

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

I have this dynamic ListView at my apk Android:

```
<android.widget.ListView resource-id="br.com.noticias:id/editoria_listview">
    <android.widget.LinearLayout>
        <android.widget.RelativeLayout>
                <android.widget.ImageView content-desc="imagem da noticia em destaque" resource-id="br.com.noticias:id/adapter_editoria_first_news_image">
        <android.widget.LinearLayout resource-id="br.com.noticias:id/adapter_editoria_layout">
            <android.widget.TextView resource-id="br.com.noticias:id/adapter_editoria_news_editoria_indicator">
            <android.widget.TextView resource-id="br.com.noticias:id/adapter_editoria_news_title">
    <android.widget.LinearLayout resource-id="br.com.noticiasbr.com.noticias:id/adapter_editoria_layout">
        <android.widget.TextView resource-id="br.com.noticias:id/adapter_editoria_news_editoria_indicator">
        <android.widget.ImageView content-desc="imagem da noticia" resource-id="br.com.noticias:id/adapter_editoria_news_image">
        <android.widget.LinearLayout>
            <android.widget.TextView resource-id="br.com.noticias:id/adapter_editoria_news_title">
    <android.widget.LinearLayout resource-id="br.com.noticias:id/adapter_editoria_layout">
        <android.widget.TextView resource-id="br.com.noticias:id/adapter_editoria_news_editoria_indicator">
        <android.widget.ImageView content-desc="imagem da noticia" resource-id="br.com.noticias:id/adapter_editoria_news_image">
        <android.widget.LinearLayout>
            <android.widget.TextView resource-id="br.com.noticias:id/adapter_editoria_news_title">
    <android.widget.LinearLayout resource-id="br.com.noticias:id/adapter_editoria_layout">
        <android.widget.TextView resource-id="br.com.noticias:id/adapter_editoria_news_editoria_indicator">
        <android.widget.ImageView content-desc="imagem da noticia" resource-id="br.com.noticias:id/adapter_editoria_news_image">
        <android.widget.LinearLayout>
            <android.widget.TextView resource-id="br.com.noticias:id/adapter_editoria_news_title">
```

I expected that this LitView returns me 4 WebElements but it's return 1.

```
List<MobileElement> listNews = driver.findElements(By.id("br.com.noticias:id/editoria_listview"));

int size = listNews.size();
System.out.println(size);
```

What am I doing wrong?
I also try with this code:

```
 java.util.Iterator<MobileElement> i = listNews.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        MobileElement row = i.next();
        System.out.println(row.getTagName());
    }
```

I also try using WebElement instead of MobileElement.
The result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are using a unique ID such that "br.com.noticias:id/editoria_listview" only has one element. Now I'm not sure if if you're looking for the title of the news but if you are you can use this ID:
"br.com.noticias:id/adapter_editoria_news_title" which should return 4 elements.